# Can I get table column headers on each page?

Tags: tables, longtable

I am making one table out of many tables and would like the headers to be at the top of each page.  I would use `\endhead` but I dont think I can put longtables in longtables.  Here is what I mean.

```
\centering

\begin{longtable}{ p{.20\textwidth}  p{.20\textwidth} p{.20\textwidth} p{.30\textwidth} } \hline

\textbf{Date Arrived} & \textbf{Ship Name} & \textbf{Capacity} & \textbf{Port} \\

\hline

\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ p{.20\textwidth}  p{.20\textwidth} p{.20\textwidth} p{.30\textwidth} }

Jan 01 2016 & Rokkosan & 300257 & Kire \\  
 & Tamba & 302159 & Sakai 2 \\  
 & Tamba & 302159 & Sakai 3 \\  
\hline & & \textbf{904575} &

\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ p{.20\textwidth}  p{.20\textwidth} p{.20\textwidth} p{.30\textwidth} }

Jan 02 2016 & Idemitsu Maru & 302159 & Chiba \\  
 & Tamba & 302159 & Sakai 2 \\  
\hline & & \textbf{604318} &

\end{longtable}
```

Comment: your example doesn't really show any problem, why can you not simply use `\endhead` in each of the `longtable` they are not nested, you just have one followed by another,

Comment: Or, if the first one is the header and the rest the content, just combine into one table - they are using the same column specifications anyway.

Comment: @cfr Any idea how I could combine these into one table and keep the formatting?  I generate these tables automatically in python from a data set.

Comment: Remove all `\end{longtable}` except the last and all `\begin{longtable}{...}` except the first ?